# не совсем ясно как работает функция flush()

Tags: php

Есть следующий небольшой код:

```
echo "<h3>Please waiting for 10 seconds...</h3>";
flush();
sleep(1);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i." ";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

В браузере сначала выводится надпись и первая цифра, потом остальные цифры с паузой между ними в 1 секунду. С этим я разобрался, вот чего я не пойму, почему не срабатывает сброс системного буфера в браузер при первой команде flush() которая идет после

`echo "<h3>Please waiting for 10 seconds...</h3>";`

Comment: Тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php в описании много особенностей работы данной функции расписано.

Comment: Там я смотрел в первую очередь, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел, почему в первом случае сброс буфера не сработал

Comment: Вот посмотрите как браузер у меня себя ведет с вашим скриптом http://jpegshare.net/images/9d/d4/9dd4d572c6b602d912cbd6905a54b864.png Отображение страницы происходит только после 11 секунд. До этого пусто, хотя получение ответа начинается быстрее 10 миллисекунд.

Comment: Ааа, это наверное потому что по умолчанию на сервере включен output_buffering, я в папке с этим файликом у себя еще создал .htaccess в котором прописал php_value output_buffering Off

Comment: У меня скрипт отработал как у вас описано, сначала выводится строка, а затем каждую секунду цифры. А какого поведения вы ожидаете, я немного не понял?

Comment: У меня строка и первая цифра выводятся одновременно, даже если я задам после первого flush() задержку в пару секунд. По идее должно было вывести строку в браузер, потом сделать паузу, потом пойдут цифры, но у меня строка и первая цифра появляются одновременно, то есть первый flush() не работает. Я не могу понять почему

Comment: @neomax, У меня отработало как вам и нужно, сначала строка, потом спустя секунду, первая цифра. Возможно настройки сервера разные.

Comment: странно, просто цифры выводятся как надо, а вот первая строка выводиться только с первой цифрой. Может быть какие настройки, вот только я не нашел нигде описания что так может влиять